# Dropping Quests in Hearthstone

Tags: hearthstone

In Blizzard's Hearthstone, you are given the option of "dropping" a quest one time per day.  This will replace it with a "random" quest.

The trouble is, some quests are worth 40 gold, others 60 and one is 100 gold.  My question is, if you drop a 60 gold quest, will you always be given another 60 gold quest, or could you end up with a 40 or the 100 gold quest?  (I have always been too fearful of losing 20 gold to test this out!)

Comment: I've only seen 40g quests. What are the ones that give 60 and 100? Aren't those single time quests?

Comment: @UnderscoreZero Check: http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Quest .  The 60 gold quests require 5 victories with one of two heroes.  The 100 gold quest requires 7 victories in any mode (including practice but I'm not sure about dueling.)

Comment: I haven't tried this as well but I know that quest are random so it strongly assume that you can roll a 40 gold quest

Comment: There are currently more daily quests available than at the time this question was asked, specifically some that reward 50 gold and a total of 3 (up from one) that reward 100 gold. This doesn't impact the essence of the question or the answer, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can end up with any quest if you reroll, so if you have a 40 gold quest and reroll there is a chance to get a 60 or 100 gold quest. The higher value quests are rarer than the 40 gold quests though in my unscientific, personal observation.

This should also work the other way around, though I haven't checked this myself as I generally don't want to waste the 20 gold. So I would not reroll 60 gold quests unless you have no reasonable deck for the heros in question or simply don't enjoy playing them.

Comment: I have tried it, and you can reroll a 60 gold quest into a 40 gold quest. Furthermore, it is possible to reroll a quest into the same quest (has happened to me, it just randomly rerolls from the full list).  Also, the first line of your question is misleading because it says "one time per quest", which is not true.  You can reroll any quest, once per day (that includes rolling the same quest over a 2nd time the following day).

Comment: @DiabloMonkey That is fantastic news! (The second part).  It was misleading because I was mislead about how you could reroll quests.  I will update this information!

Comment: @BlackVegetable Maybe it is just me, but your question still reads misleadingly.  I would change it to, "In Blizzard's Hearthstone, you are given the option of "dropping" (rerolling) one of your quests, one time per day." I would leave out any reference to "per quest" because you can store up to 3 quests and you can pick any one of them to reroll and do that once per day.  If you only completed 1, and the following day you get a new 1, and still have 3, you could at that point reroll any 1 of those 3 again. Make sense?

Comment: @DiabloMonkey Agreed.